# How to calculate no. of complex words(Words containing more than two vowels) from a list of words in python?

Tags: python, nlp

I want to calculate the number of words containing more than two vowels from a list of words.

Comment: clearify your question , upload some code with desire output.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please look at the guidelines to ask questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
count = 0

for myword in mylist:
    d = {}.fromkeys('aeiou',0)
    haslotsvowels = False
    for x in myword.lower():
        if x in d:
            d[x] += 1
    for q in d.values():
        if q > 2:
            haslotsvowels = True
    if haslotsvowels:
        count += 1
        
print(count)
```

Comment: I have a list of words and want to count words with more than two vowels from that list.

Comment: code edited to act on Python List of words (called mylist).

Comment: thanks a lot .it helped me create a function and calculate the complex words from 111 text documents separately.